# Question regarding the status of Erdős' conjectures

Tags: conjectures, open-problem

Has [Erdős' conjecture on arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions) or his [conjecture on Sylvester's sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_sequence#Uniqueness_of_quickly_growing_series_with_rational_sums) been proven?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think "Erdős's conjectures" would be more correct, though. The fact that *s* is pronounced as *sh* here suggests that the possessive form should be treated in the same way as "Bush's".

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the 1st conjecture remains open. I don't know about the second one.

Comment: Reminds me of a limerick I saw over forty years ago

Answer (score 0):

The first conjecture is wide open. It is - roughly speaking - equivalent to proving Szemeredi's theorem with extremely good bounds. Even if you just ask for progressions of length $3$, then the best known bounds are not strong enough. If you start talking about arbitrary length, the bounds become appropriately worse.